# Ubuntu 16.04 with no swap freezes when running out of memory

Tags: 16.04, swap, memory-usage

I have an up-to-date 16.04 64bit system with 24GB of memory, configured without swap. Sometimes due to the nature of my work (multiple VirtualBox VMs running, Eclipse running, Firefox and Chrome running etc) my system runs out of memory and instead of killing the processes with the larger memory footprint it just freezes and becomes unusable and then I have to hard reboot. Why is this the case?

Comment: I think that, even if you have 24GB or RAM, you need at least 5 GB of RAM (in my opinion the best would be 24GB). Maybe there is a problem with swapiness... if you run in a terminal as root the command: `sysctl vm.swappiness` what it returns?

Comment: It returns: vm.swappiness = 60

Comment: You can try, as root, to execute `sysctl vm.swappiness=0` . This disable the swap, maybe the system try to allocate the swap even if there is not...

Comment: Nope, this didn't change anything, as expected since I don't have any swap file as I explained before.

Comment: @TryfonFarmakakis did you find a solution? could you help me?

Comment: 14.04 freezes all the same. Looks like OOM killer is not active by default in Ubuntu, or am I misunderstanding something?